# Cannot find custom application

Tags: facebook, web

This is going to sound like a really dumb question, but we had a developer who created a Facebook web application for us.

He has left the company and is not being very co operative. We have the log in details of the account he used to created the app, but when we log in and try to view the app, it does not appear in our list of custom apps.

In the graph explorer, when trying to debug the key and URL, the app does appear in the drop down though, but we need to change some other custom settings.

Can anyone direct me in which direction I need to go to look for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked for it under https://developers.facebook.com/apps when logged in with his account?

Comment: Aye. Finally. got him to let us log in and that is where it was. All that time wasted for nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally. got him to let us log in and that is where it was. All that time wasted for nothing.